# std::make_pair: "cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘std::pair<EndPointAddr*, EndPointAddr*>*’ in initialization"

Tags: c++, c++11, std-pair

In below listed function, I am trying create a pointer to an std::pair object where I get a compilation error shown at the bottom of this message (The related line number has been marked in the code snippet below). Could you please tell me what's wrong with this code? Thanks.

```
 void 
 XXX::addSubscription(EndPointAddr* ptrRequesterServiceAddr, 
                      EndPointAddr* ptrRequestedServiceAddr)
 {
  //LINE 908 indicated in the g++ output starts HERE
  std::pair<EndPointAddr*, EndPointAddr* > *thePair = 
  new  std::make_pair(ptrRequesterServiceAddr, ptrRequestedServiceAddr);

  mServiceSubscriptionsList.push_back(thePair); 
 }
```

**Compilation Output:**

```
 ../XXX.cpp: 
 In member function ‘void XXX::addSubscription(EndPointAddr*, EndPointAddr*)’:
 ../XXX.cpp:908:59: error: expected type-specifier
 ../XXX.cpp:908:59: error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘std::pair<EndPointAddr*, EndPointAddr*>*’ in initialization
 ../XXX.cpp:908:59: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’
```

Comment: Why do you need to create a dynamic pair object. Why not use std::pair<EndPointAddr*, EndPointAddr* > thePair; and then thePair = std::make_pair(ptrRequesterServiceAddr, ptrRequestedServiceAddr); And the mServiceSubscriptionsList.push_back(&thePair);

Comment: @VaibhavDesai, because `thePair` will be destroyed after the function ends. So, you will have a dangling pointer.

Comment: ^ Thank you. Missed it completely.

Comment: @H2CO3 "Hungarian notation is hard to read. – H2CO3" Says a native Hungarian. :)

Comment: @Ali Yeah, even with my Hungarian nationality, I find that convention brainless ;-)

Comment: @Ali Well. That's for Fortran programmers, it's not C++-esque, is it? (Keblemre, barátom! :D Dobj egy e-mailt!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::pair<EndPointAddr*, EndPointAddr* > *thePair = 
  new  std::make_pair(ptrRequesterServiceAddr, ptrRequestedServiceAddr);
            ^^^^^^
```

should be

```
std::pair<EndPointAddr*, EndPointAddr* > *thePair = 
  new  std::pair<EndPointAddr*, EndPointAddr*>(ptrRequesterServiceAddr, ptrRequestedServiceAddr);
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`std::make_pair` is a function. You are trying to assign an `std::pair` pointer to a function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use constructor instead of make pair instead of std::make_pair

```
  std::pair<EndPointAddr*, EndPointAddr* > *thePair = 
  new  std::pair<EndPointAddr*, EndPointAddr* >(ptrRequesterServiceAddr, ptrRequestedServiceAddr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example code does not show the type of `mServiceSubscriptionsList` which would be helpful to know.

Try this:

```
void 
 XXX::addSubscription(EndPointAddr* ptrRequesterServiceAddr, 
                      EndPointAddr* ptrRequestedServiceAddr)
 {
  //LINE 908 indicated in the g++ output starts HERE
  std::pair<EndPointAddr*, EndPointAddr* > thePair = 
  std::make_pair(ptrRequesterServiceAddr, ptrRequestedServiceAddr);

  mServiceSubscriptionsList.push_back(thePair); 
 }
```